# How to save array of data in Firebase database from Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to **Firebase Database**, I just want to Save the array of data in Firebase database. when I am trying to save it shows error. Below I mentioned the **POJO Class** and **Logcat** Error while save the data.

**POJO Class Coding**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class StudentReviews {

public String student_name;
public String student_class;
public String student_image;
public String student_section;

public ArrayList<Reviews> reviewsList = new ArrayList<>();

public void StudentReviews() {}

public class Reviews {
        public String subject;
        public String marks_taken;
        public String total_marks;
        public String teacher;
    }
}
```

**Saving Data**

```
StudentReviews studentReviews = new StudentReviews();
studentReviews.student_name = et_studentName.getText().toString();
studentReviews.student_class = et_student_class.getText().toString();
studentReviews.student_image = "";
studentReviews.student_section = sp_section.getSelectedItem().toString();
studentReviews.reviewsList = reviewsArray;

dbUploadReview.push().setValue(studentReviews); //165th Line in Logcat Error
```

**Logcat Error**

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: this$0. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtf.zzjq(Unknown Source)   
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtf.zzay(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtf.zzay(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtf.zzay(Unknown Source)  
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
at com.trending.trendingadmin.fragment.WriteReview.uploadReviews(WriteReview.java:165)
```

When I remove this `public ArrayList<Reviews> reviewsList = new ArrayList<>();` reviewsList in **POJO Class**  data saved in Firebsae database perfectly.

Anyone know help me to solve this issue.

**Update**

I am Solved this problem by Two Ways. Suggestion given by **OlegOsipenko**

> 1) Make the inner class as static
>
> 2) Moving the inner class to another file.

Now its work well and good as i expected.

Comment: What is line 165 of WriteReview.java?

Comment: Also please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Yugesh  your data must not contain  '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'.It means your data subject or teacher  or marks or dbUploadReview  may have that symbols.try once with only characters or numbers to find occuring same issue..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `dbUploadReview.push().setValue(StudentReviews);` This piece of coding in 165th Line.

Comment: Please read the link I gave above and [edit] your question.

Comment: @NarenderReddy Am Checked. Data does not contain any of those symbols.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Am edited my Question.

Comment: could  you share screenshot of your firebase database ..

Comment: Please provide example data which is entered before the error occurs.

Comment: Don't know how do you instantiate the `reviewsArray` variable, because the code you provided won't compile for me, saying 'Reviews is not an enclosing class'. 
Moving this class to another file or making it static inner class results in successful storing of the file. Look https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHD6P.png

Comment: And by the way, change the type of your `reviewsList` variable to be interface `List` type instead of specific implementation. And why do you initialise it to the ArrayList instance? Anyway you'll assign to this variable another List object, and you're just performing unnecessary allocations, loading your GC with extra work

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Can i provide the JSON Structure of this Data.How can i expect to save.

Comment: @Yugesh actually your code is almost ok. Try to make `Reviews` class `static` and run

Comment: @OlegOsipenko okay i will try that.

Comment: @OlegOsipenko As of your both suggestion save data without error. 1) Make `Review`class as `static` 2) Moving the `Review` class to another file.

Answer (score 2):

As your Logcat error says `Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`, which means that each one of this symbols is not allowed as a key in `Firebase database`.

In order to write data objects to your Firebase database, in stead of using a `List`, i suggest you to use a `Map`. You need also to make this change in your pojo class. To save data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference namesRef = rootRef.child("names");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("nameId1", "John");
map.put("nameId2", "Tim");
map.put("nameId3", "Sam");
//and os on
namesRef.updateChildren(map);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, See my Question Update.

Answer (score 1):

The .setValue() method needs a List rather than an Array. You can use List of object.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
String[] names = {"John","Tim","Sam","Ben"};
List nameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
// Now set value with new nameList
ref.setValue(nameList);
```

[Read the Firebase docs for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-push)